# Using optional chaining with array.entries

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

Just trying to understand optional chaining and unsure if it can be used in the following situation with `.entries`, that is:

```
for (const [index, val] of Array.from(myArray)?.entries()) {
  if (val.status === 1) {
      . . . 
       . . . 
  }
}
```

I basically don't want to proceed if `myArray` is empty.

Comment: It doesn’t do anything in that situation. `Array.from` never returns null or undefined. But if an array is empty, iterating over it doesn’t do anything anyway.

Comment: @Ry- Appreciate the explanation. So if `myArray` is empty to begin with, then this part of the code will not crash out - correct?

Comment: Right. And if it’s already an array, there’s no need to use `Array.from` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for a short null check, I think your problem is not from `Array.from` but it's from `myArray` variable. If `myArray` is undefined, `Array.from(myArray)?.entries()` will throw an error

```
const myArray = undefined
const entries = Array.from(myArray)?.entries() //throw an error
```

[image]

If you want to overcome this, you need to use [short circuit evaluation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/short-circuit-evaluation-in-javascript) to assign the default value `[]` whenever `myArray` is undefined or null

```
const myArray = undefined
const entries = Array.from(myArray || []).entries() //working!
```

[image]

If `myArray` is already an array (or possibly an undefined value), you can get rid of `Array.from` too

```
const myArray = undefined
const entries = myArray?.entries() || [] //assign a default value for your loop
```